# GeoFire alternative for static locations

Tags: firebase, geofire

I want to query for locations near by the user from Firebase.
I stumbled over GeoFire and, while it does work, I am unsure if it is the best way to go. As far as I understand the main idea of GeoFire is that the locations are moving and updated to the user. In my case they are static, so it is probably a bit of an overkill.

Is there another solution to query near by locations from firebase, without using serverside logic and downloading a lot more data than needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use geoFire to get the locations of things around the user for one time. The way to do that is by

1- running a geoQuery and get all the keys around.

2- then removing all the listeners on the geoQuery.

To remove listeners after you get the locations, in android for example, call `geoQuery.removeAllListeners();` in `onGeoQueryReady()` function